# Git merge from same branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

I have a single branch in the form of:

```
 a --> b --> c
 ^           ^
 |           |
main        dev
```

I want to make another connection between `a` and `c`. A visual:

```
 ----> b --->
 |          |
 a -------> c
 ^          ^
 |          |
main       dev
```

How would I do this with git? Is it possible?

Comment: have a look at this : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge.

Comment: Are a,b,c commits?

Comment: @JRichardsz Yes, they are commits. Apologies for not clarifying that in my question.

Comment: Using `git merge` while `c` is the current commit won't do anything because the snapshot in such a merge would match that in `c` and the history (ancestry graph) wouldn't really be different in any useful way. See [eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70136409/1256452) for how to make such a commit anyway, but: *why?*

Comment: Note, by the way, that in Git the arrows go "backwards", from child to parent. An is-ancestor test has to work from the child/grand^n-child backwards to see if the other commit is a parent/grandparent/grand^n-parent.

Comment: @torek What I wanted was for the `main` branch to not see the intermediate changes `b` to keep that branch clean. I understand that it's good to keep branches as clean as possible, but also didn't want to delete `b` to preserve history. I understand I could also make a commit `d` from `main`, then merge it with `c`, but that would clutter the tree with a "filler" commit `d`.

Is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Commit `b` will be on the chain of commits, no matter how you go about this. It's either that, or commit `c` *won't* be on the chain of commits: you could make a new commit `d` that does not connect to `c` in any way, but has the same *snapshot* as commit `c`. But then neither `b` nor `c` are part of the sequence that ends in `d`: `d` links back only to `a`. The command that achieves this `d`-links-to-`a`-but-matches-`c`'s-snapshot is `git checkout main; git merge --squash dev`, after which you would generally *delete* `dev` which has now outlived its usefulness.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to keep the *contents* of c in the new revision:

```
git commit-tree -p main -p b -m "one comment" c^{tree}
```

That will give you a revision id as the result. Feel free to check it with `git log` or `git checkout`.... when you feel like that is what you want:

```
git branch -f dev the-id
```

And you are done